# CoronaSDK Changing Font Style

Tags: fonts, lua, coronasdk

I have been looking around on the Corona documentation but I haven't seen anything to change the font style of a display.newText object. I know when you first create the object you can set the font parameter to be whatever you like. I know you can also do custom fonts by adding the font names to your build settings file. However what I want to do is change the fontstyle of text after the display.newText has already been declared. What I am trying is this:

```
local text = display.newText("title", display.contentWidth/2, display.contentHeight/2, native.systemFont, 12)

text.font = "Comic Sans MS"
```

The code above does not give any errors in the terminal but the font does not change. 
Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this tut on how to use Custom fonts
http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/07/13/custom-fonts-corona/

EDIT

ok. I did not read your question fully.  You want to change the font on the fly.
I guess the only way is to remove the display object and reinsert it with a new font.

Something like

```
local text = display.newText("title", display.contentWidth/2, display.contentHeight/2, native.systemFont, 12)


--After some time
local txt = text.text
local size = text.size
local left = text.contentBounds.xMin
local top  = text.contentBounds.yMin 

text:removeSelf()
text = display.newText(txt, left, top, "Comic Sans MS",size)
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid doing that but it seems there is no other way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[The Text object doesn't support that.](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/text-display-objects). It has an anemic interface in general (you can see a related complaint on that page from 5 months ago). [See here, as well.](http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2010/03/03/set-font-text-object-iterate-over-obejct-properties)

(SIDE NOTE: If you're a fairly experienced developer and aren't deep into a project yet, one alternative would be switching to MOAI, which is free, open source, with a much more heavily factored, flexible API. You'd have completely control over text ([MOAITextBox](http://getmoai.com/docs/class_m_o_a_i_text_box.html), [MOAITextStyle](http://getmoai.com/docs/class_m_o_a_i_text_style.html), [MOAIFont](http://getmoai.com/docs/class_m_o_a_i_font.html)), among other things. However, it's also *much* less user friendly.)